# Getting this annoying message "Avoid using private types in public APIs"

Tags: flutter

I seen it work in older flutter versions on Youtube. But with new flutter updates keep getting that annoying message. What do I have to do to fix it?

```
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
```

Answer (score 1):

This solved it

```
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
```

Found out from this link - https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/103773
mraleph